# How are objects in JavaScript stored in memory?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

On the official documentation of [JSON](http://www.json.org)

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins
>   with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is
>   followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by ,
>   (comma).

**Note**
I am Javascript newbie, and from the name JSON (Javascript object notation) itself, I am assuming objects in Javascript are same as JSON. Please correct me in case I have got it wrong.

From the above definition it seems the Javascript objects are most probably implemented by either a hashmap or a BST or some similar data-structure.

But when I insert key value pairs in **Node** shell, they are inserted in serialised manner. This is what I tried in node shell

```
> var a = {}
undefined
> a['k1'] = 'a1'
'a1'
> a['k3'] = 'a3'
'a3'
> a['k2'] = 'a2'
'a2'
> a['k4'] = 'a4'
'a4'
> a['k5'] = 'a5'
'a5'
> a
{ k1: 'a1',
  k3: 'a3',
  k2: 'a2',
  k4: 'a4',
  k5: 'a5' }
```

Now, on printing `a` the key value pairs are returned in the same order as that of insertion. So my questions are:

- Do I get fast lookups for a key? I mean complexity of O(log(n)) or better.
- In case JSON is not using a data-structure like a BST, hashmap or some similar DS, then how exactly are JSON objects layed under the memory?

**Update**
Ok, so what about Javascript objects. Can someone comment on the underlying implementation of Javascript objects.

Comment: JSON is a notation, like XML is another one. It's highly based on Javascript objects though, hence the name. Other than that, there's no relation.

Comment: There are no "JSON objects". Even the name should tell that ("object notation object"?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're confusing [JSON](http://json.org/), which is **only** a text-based serialization format enabling simple data exchange, and plain javascript objects, which are **unordered** lists of properties.

As said by [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) :

> An object is a collection of properties, and a property is association
> between a name and a value. A value of property can be a function,
> which is then known as the object's method.

Objects properties can be seen as hash maps, as they're not ordered. But it's often a little more complicated : when objects are prototype based, properties not found on an object are searched upward the prototypes it's based on.

With javascript objects you get a guaranteed fast look-up, as this is an essential part of the implementation. But the implementation isn't defined by the norm and each engine can have its own.

**Update**

Starting from ES6, which you have in almost all browsers and JS servers in 2021, the order of non integer keys in object is the insertion order.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It really did clarified a lot of misconceptions. :)

Comment: Is there any reason why I am getting Javascript object getting printed in serialized fashion (same as order of insertion), unlike Python's dictionary or C++ STL map.

Comment: I said it's not normalized but it's, for now, an undocumented (and unguaranteed) feature. See this discustion about it : http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time and help. Sorry in case I was annoying :(

Comment: Don't worry. Annoying questions are downvoted and often closed. Why keys appear to be ordered or whether they should be aren't trivial questions at all ;)